# How to filter by boolean field in search bar - django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter, searchbar, django-q

I'm working on a Django project that is a project management system.
Basically in the navbar, I've implemented a searcher to search for specific projects like the title, the client, the description, etc.

I'd like to give them the possibility of searching also the projects that are urgent (urgent in my Project model is a boolean field), but the way I implemented it doesn't work.

This is my Project Model:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    urgent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    deadline = models.DateField()
    ...
```

To make the search bar (that in my html file is:)

```html
<form method="get" class="form-inline">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="q" id="id_q" type="text" placeholder="Search..." aria-label="Search" value="{{query}}">

  <button class="btn btn-outline-dark my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
      <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-search" fill="currentColor"
           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M10.442 10.442a1 1 0 0 1 1.415 0l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 1-1.414 1.415l-3.85-3.85a1 1 0 0 1 0-1.415z"/>
          <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                d="M6.5 12a5.5 5.5 0 1 0 0-11 5.5 5.5 0 0 0 0 11zM13 6.5a6.5 6.5 0 1 1-13 0 6.5 6.5 0 0 1 13 0z"/>
      </svg>
  </button>
</form>
```

How I've implemented this function:

```py
def get_projects_qs(proj, query=None):
    queryset = []
    queries = query.split(" ")

    for q in queries:

        projects = proj.filter( Q(title__icontains=q) | Q(description__icontains=q) | Q(urgent__icontains=q) | Q(client__client__icontains=q) ).distinct()

        for project in projects:
            queryset.append(project)

    return list(set(queryset))
```

Now, if I do Q(urgent_icontains=q) it doesn't work, but if I do Q(urgent=q) it works only the first time and then I get this error:

```
ValidationError at /marketing/
['“” value must be either True or False.']
```

Comment: your question is unclear. ask again carefully with all detail about what do you want to do and provide full code

Comment: I'm sorry, English is not my first language and I'm just starting coding. I'll try to explain better... I have several project objects that among other things have a title, a description and an URGENT status that is a boolean. With the serachbar I can search a project for its title or description, but I cannot search project that have the urgent attribute set to True. I used Q lookups to make the searcher work, but it doesn't work for the urgent field and I don't know what to try

Comment: ok. i will suggest a structure that user can choose if a product is urgent or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's assume we have a model like this:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    urgent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    .
    .
    .
```

views.py:

```
from . models import Product


def is_valid_queryparam(param):
    return param != '' and param is not None


def search(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    search = request.GET.get('search')
    complete = request.GET.get('complete')
    urgent = request.GET.get('urgent')


    if is_valid_queryparam(search):
        queryset = queryset.filter(title__icontains=search)

    if is_valid_queryparam(complete):
        queryset = queryset.filter(complete=True)

    elif is_valid_queryparam(urgent):
        queryset = queryset.filter(urgent=True)

    context = {
        'queryset': queryset
    }

    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```

now in template ( search.html ):

```
<form id="mySearch" method="GET">
    <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    <button" type="submit">Click to Search</button>

    <input type="checkbox" name="complete" id="checkbox-1" onchange="$('#mySearch').submit();" {% if request.GET.complete == 'on' %} checked {% endif %}>
    <label for="checkbox-1">complete</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="urgent" id="checkbox-2" onchange="$('#mySearch').submit();" {% if request.GET.urgent == 'on' %} checked {% endif %}>
    <label for="checkbox-2">urgent</label>
</form>
```

Comment: Glad I was able to help.consider this search returns urgents or completed products. if you want to return both urgents and completed , use if instead of elif condition in the last filter param